# URL changing but view is not changing in React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am using react router 4 not react router 3 so I am using react-router-dom. I am trying to get this.props.history.push to work, but all it is doing is keeping the view the same, but the URL changes.

For example I click the button and it calls a function which just calls this.props.history.push('/posts'). The url changes from localhost:3000/signin to localhost:3000/posts. But I am still on my signin view.

If I hit refresh however it will redirect to the posts page. I have looked at other questions and those people could not get it to go there no matter what, even if they refreshed or went into the url and hit enter.

I will post the code below to see what I am doing wrong. Also I am using react router v4 not 3. I cannot use browserHistory.push and other things that v3 used.

Code:

component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class Signin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  renderField(field) {
    const { meta: {touched, error} } = field;
    const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`;

    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label><strong>{field.label}:</strong></label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type={field.type}
          {...field.input}
        />
        <div className="text-help">
          { touched ? error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSubmit({email, password}) {
    // this.props.signinUser({email, password}, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/posts');
    // });
  }

  renderAlert() {
    if(this.props.errorMessage) {
      return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger">
          <strong>Oops</strong> {this.props.errorMessage}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
        <Field
          label="Email"
          name="email"
          type="email"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Field
          label="Password"
          name="password"
          type="password"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        {this.renderAlert()}
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};

  //Validate the inputs from values
  if(!values.email) {
    errors.email = "Enter an email!";
  }
  if(!values.password) {
    errors.password = "Enter a password!";
  }
  //If errors is empty, the form is fine to submit
  //If errors has any properties, redux form assumes form is invalid
  return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    errorMessage: state.auth.error
  };
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'signin'
})(connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(withRouter(Signin)));
```

action:

```
export function signinUser({email, password}, cb) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/signin`, {email, password})
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: AUTH_USER});
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);

      })
      .then(() => cb())
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(authError(error.response.data.error));
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found out the problem was not within the code I posted but how I was doing my routes. Make sure when you are routing you are not nesting routes as components as your routes. For example I had:

```
const Routes = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)
```

Here I had imported App as a component (or it was exported as a component), I changed it from a component to a normal function. To make this more clear I will put old code and new code below:

Old:

```
class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path="/signin" component={RequireUnAuth(Signin)} />
      <Route path="/signout" component={Signout} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
      <Route path="/posts" component={Posts} />
    </Switch>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

New:

```
const App = () => (
   <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path="/signin" component={RequireUnAuth(Signin)} />
      <Route path="/signout" component={Signout} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
      <Route path="/posts" component={Posts} />
    </Switch>
   </div>
  )
```

This is the App that was being exported and once I switched to a simple function instead of a component based class everything worked. I didn't have to do hard refreshes, I can click back and it goes back, redirecting with this.props.history.push works, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of react-router-redux installed (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux), with React Router 4 support. In package.json:

`"react-router-redux": "next"`

Next, follow the instructions on adding history middleware to your redux store. Link: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions

Once you have the correct package, and middleware installed, you need to import the reducer into your index reducer e.g.:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {routerReducer} from 'react-router-redux';

const IndexReducer = combineReducers({
    router: routerReducer,
    //...other reducers go here
});

export default IndexReducer;
```

Then, import the push method wherever you would like to dispatch it (e.g. actions.js):

`import {push} from 'react-router-redux';`

And then use it like so:

`dispatch(push('/your/route/here'));`

Comment: I am using react-router-dom not react-router-redux

Comment: I do not have react-router-redux sorry

Comment: This is not with react-router-redux but with react-router-dom, could you please reply if is the same for both? I have not been able to get this to work.