# React-router browserHIstory.push() does not redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I saw lots of similar questions on StackOverflow, but the suggested solutions did not work for me. It's also possible that I did not know how to best apply it, as I am new to React. A MCVE of my code is as below:

```
export default class ClDashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      start: this.props.location.query.start,
      end: this.props.location.query.end,
      period: this.props.location.query.period,
      autoRotate: false
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState(this.newProps(this.props))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.autoRotate) {
      let nextID = this.getNextID(this.props.route.clientInfo.farms)

      let [startDate, endDate] = this.getAutoRotateDates()
      let timeQuery = '/?start=' + startDate + '&end=' + endDate

      let farmChange = this.farmChange.bind(this)
      let farmChangeHandle = () => {
        if (this.state.autoRotate) { 
          farmChange(nextID, timeQuery)
        }
      }
      setTimeout(farmChangeHandle, 3000)
    }
  }

farmChange = (ID, timeQuery) => {
        browserHistory.push(this.state.url + ID + timeQuery)
    }
```

Essentially what happens is, I am trying to rotate between a set of IDs (`getNextID()` gets the next ID in sequence) if a certain flag `autoRotate` is set to true. However, though the URL changes to the next ID, the page does not reflect the changes.

I tried the following things:
- I don't think the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509790/url-changing-but-view-is-not-changing-in-react-router-4) is applicable to my case, but if it is, would like to know how.
- My version of react-router is 3.0.5 so solutions like [these for v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4) would not work
- Tried adding `componentWillReceiveProps()` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526825/browserhistory-push-doesnt-navigate-to-new-page) but that did not help either.

One strange thing is that if I copy everything within `if (this.state.autoRotateFarms)` to `componentWillReceiveProps()`, then it works, but it seems to redirect the page back to the next ID in the sequence even after you navigate away.

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: why cant you update to 4

Comment: I want to know of how to do it without updating, because there must be a way to do it. Moreover, updating requirements might affect the codebase in other ways that I can't track, so I'd like to avoid it if possible.